# error: failed reading sector 0x2dcc6840 of "hd1". error: kernel must be loaded first. Press any key to continue..._

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have two ssd disks in my laptop. In hd0 I installed windows 10, and in hd1 I installed Ubuntu 22.04. First day after two installations, windows and ubuntu run started correcty from ubuntu grub, but some days later when grub starts and y select Ubuntu, I see this notification and Ubuntu doesn't start:

error: failed reading sector 0x2dcc6840 of "hd1".

error: kernel must be loaded first.

Press any key to continue..._

Any solution for this error?

Comment: Have you checked the health of your drive?  Failing to read a sector usually means hardware problems (related to drive, PSU, even RAM etc).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   *Note:  turning a machine off or poor user behavior can cause corruption issues that can destroy data thus reading as if hardware issues, but we're limited to details you provide which is a failure to read data (linux kernel) from your disk*

Comment: As Windows has full access to the disk any bug (or feature) in Windows (or the apps) can break the second OS. Windows does only care about itself and will not hinder the Windows "Admin" to break other OS without notice. E.g. Diskmanager writes "signatures" to "unknown" disks.